# Обновлённые данные в LisvtView отображаются только при повторном открытии фрагмента

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, android-asynctask

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы ListView заполнялся обновлёнными данными при первом открытии. Сейчас приходится переходить в другой фрагмент и возвращаться в нужный.
С помощью myClass.myFunction() данные подтягиваются из Firebase, сравниваются с хранящимися данными в SQLite и обновляются при необходимости. Обновление проходит при первом открытии фрагмента и это видно в логах, но в ListView отображаются устаревшие данные.

```
public class Root_Exercises_Fragment_v2 extends BaseFragment {
    public static final String TAG = "TAG1";
    private ListView mListview;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayout, container, false);
        new AsyncClass().execute();
        mListview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mListview);
        return view;

    }

    class AsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... parameter) {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass(getActivity());
            myClass.myFunction();
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.v("TAG", "In postExecute");
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
            database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), database.rawQuery(getString(R.string.myQuery), null)) {
            };
            mListview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Обновление проходит при первом открытии фрагмента и это видно в логах, но в ListView отображаются устаревшие данные." - обновление чего? Базы данных? т.е. обновление базы данных есть, но в `ListView` показываются старые данные?

Comment: @Iman< да, обновление БД (скачиваются и добавляются новые объекты + обновляются новые). Да, в ListView отображаются старые данные.

Comment: Наверно `AsyncTask` сразу к методу `onPostExecute` переходит, не дождавшись завершения, попробуйте завернуть все в `try` и поставить `finnaly` и там прописать `return null;`

Comment: @Iman, увы, не помогло, но получилось выяснить, что данные не подтягиваются только если в локальной бд пусто. Если в бд есть хоть одна запись, то все последующие записи отображаются в ListView без необходимости повторного входа во фрагмент.

Comment: Если в локальной бд пусто, то откуда тогда, `ListView` заполняется старыми данными?

Comment: Там пусто только до выполнения myClass.myFunction(). К моменту перехода к mAdapter = new MyAdapter(...) в бд уже есть данные.